# How to Get child element's value based on clicked Radio button

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

Below is my code It's Generating a list  through foreach loop and it's Radio button's Id remains same in all Auto Generated Radio buttons so I am unable to get specifice value based on Radio  button selection, so please ther is any  option to get value.

```
<div id="divaddress" data-bind="foreach: Addresslist">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="i-boxb">
            <input class="checkout-radio" type="radio" name="existingaddress" id="exadressid" data-bind="click:GetAddressId" @*onclick="GetAddressId()"*@ />
            <label class="cradio" for="normal" data-bind="text:Name" style="font-weight:bold"> </label>
            <p data-bind="text:Address"></p>
            <p data-bind="text:City"></p>
            <p data-bind="text:State"></p>
            <p data-bind="text:Pincode"></p>
            <p id="Mobileno" data-bind="text:Mobile"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: to make it more comfortable, could you copy and paste the code instead of posting a screenshot?

Comment: For example  when I run this code it can generate two or three lists from data base. so,  bases on Radio button selection I need to get value of it's child element.

Comment: Could you provide a full example of what this is supposed to be able to do? It's just that it's hard to understand you, sorry.

Comment: are you expecting that functionality where you have a list of addresses with a checkbox (like on shopping sites which ask you to choose your address)

Comment: yes  @adiga I need same functionality to accomplice my task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a list of addresses with a checkbox in each them. And you want to get the `Id` of the address when the user checks on it (like on shopping websites)

You have to add a property called `selectedAddressId` to your view model.

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedAddressId = ko.observable();
    self.Addresslist = ko.observableArray([
        { Id: 1, Address: "Number 10", City: "London" },
        { Id: 2, Address: "Number 420", City: "Delhi" },
    ]);

    // this will subscribe to the radio selection changes
    self.selectedAddressId.subscribe(function (selectedValue) {
        // all the logic you want on selecting of checkbox goes here
        alert(selectedValue);
    });
};
```

Then in your HTML, you can use the [`checked`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) binding. You need to bind the `Id` of the address to the `value` of radio input

```
<div id="divaddress" data-bind="foreach: Addresslist">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="i-boxb">
            <input class="checkout-radio" type="radio" name="selectedAddressId" data-bind="value:id, checked: $parent.selectedAddressId"  />
            <label class="cradio" for="normal" data-bind="text:Name" style="font-weight:bold"> </label>
            <p data-bind="text:Address"></p>
            <p data-bind="text:City"></p>
            <p data-bind="text:State"></p>
            <p data-bind="text:Pincode"></p>
            <p id="Mobileno" data-bind="text:Mobile"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the `$parent.selectedAddressId` in the radio binding. Without `$parent`, knockout would look for a `selectedAddressId` property in your `Address` object and not in your parent viewModel

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqUAz/1630/)

Comment: Thank you  @adiga for explaining in Detail. I want to get only Mobile Number on radio button click, no Address Id. how do it ?

Comment: You can do 2 things: either filter your `Addresslist` and get the object where `Id` is the selected Id. *Or* if you just need the phone number, you can simply bind the `Mobile` property to the `value` of radio input. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/dqUAz/1631/